Is there a way to use multiple Ldr inside a darkness sensor?
im trying to make a darkness sensor with mulpiple LDRs, the idea is that if all the LDRs are in the dark, a light in a led strip is turn on, otherwise, the led strip stays off. I have manage to make it work with one, but i can't make a second LDR to function as intended. im very new to electronics so any help is apreciated.

You can connect multiple LDRs in parallel, so that if any one of them is illuminated, then their combined resistance falls precipitously, and switches off the transistor:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Your own circuit doesn't make much sense to me, at least the way it's drawn, so I've modified it a little so it should work as I've drawn it.
You'll probably have to experiment with different values of R2, until the switching threshold is right for you, and for whatever LDRs and transistor you are using. If you find the LED difficult to switch on, then reduce R2, and vice versa.

thanks for the help, i used that configuration because i thought the LED RGB strip needed to be connected directly to the positive and the colors are the negative, that way i can, for example use red for the LDRs and maybe blue for a switch and the colors could function independently. i will try that configuration and see if it work, thanks again.

LED strip may have resistors.
